# Is a broken (Euclidean) ball still convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Consider the Euclidean ball $B^n(x,r)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ given by:
$$B^n(x,r) = \{z\in\mathbb{R}^n : ||z-x||_2 \leq r\}$$ with centre $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and radius $r\geq 0$.
Now we **break** this ball by ***removing an arbitrary subset from the boundary*** of $B^n(x,r)$. Is the resulting set still convex?

My intuition says *Yes*, and it's easy to visualise this in $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$. I'm wondering how I can prove it generally, i.e. for $\mathbb{R}^n$ by considering an arbitrary subset $S\subseteq B^n(x,r)$? If $S = B^n(x,r)$ then the resulting set is empty, which is convex - so we can ignore that situation. We assume $S\subset B^n(x,r)$. What's next?

I consider two points $y_1,y_2 \in B^n(x,r)\backslash S$, and want to show that for $t\in [0,1]$ we have $ty_1 + (1-t)y_2 \in B^n(x,r)\backslash S$. How do I take it from here? I'm stuck.

Thanks!

**Addendum**:
What if we consider the $p$-norm in general, instead of the Euclidean norm? How do things change with $p$ if the ball is defined as follows?
$$B^n(x,r) = \{z\in\mathbb{R}^n : ||z-x||_p \leq r\}$$
*It sounds fun breaking balls in higher dimensions under different norms!*

Comment: see this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232276/show-that-the-unit-sphere-is-strictly-convex

Comment: $S\subseteq B^n(x,r)$ is not enough. You need $S$ to be a subset of the **boundary** of $B^n(x,r)$.

Comment: @DavidK What's a rigorous way of writing that?

Comment: For your addendum, try $p=\frac 12, 1, \infty$

Comment: You wrote it rigorously at the beginning of your question. If you want a concise mathematical notation for "boundary of $B^n(x,r)$", you might try $\partial B^n(x,r)$.

Comment: A line connecting two points in the closed ball will only meet the boundary in its endpoints if they are boundary points.

Comment: As hinted by ThePortakal’s comments above, your problem is equivalent to the given norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ being strictly convex, which is the case for the Euclidean norm (and $p$-norm for $1<p<\infty$).

Comment: Note that this does fail for $p=1$ and $p=\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To simplify notation, I'll assume, without loss of generality, that the center of the ball is at the origin.
Suppose, toward a contradiction, that you have a counterexample in some high dimension. Say your set contains $p$ and $q$ but not some point $tp+(1-t)q$ on the line segment joining $p$ to $q$. Then this is also a counterexample in the $2$-dimensional subspace spanned by (the vectors from the origin to) $p$ and $q$. So, once you know the result for $2$ dimensions, it follows for all higher dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Along every (parametrised by $t$) line, the squared Euclidean norm is a quadratic function in $t$ and does not attain a value $\ge1$ between distinct points where it is $\le1$.